# What's the furthest possible range that an unarmed strike could have?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, monk, unarmed-combat, reach

From what I have seen, the furthest that I could get it was 20 feet, however, I'm sure it's possible to increase it further, so, how far can an unarmed strike truly reach?

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111256/what-build-maximizes-reach/113595#113595
The top answer happens to involve an unarmed strike.

Comment: Can we use Unearthed Arcana?

Comment: Related: "[What is the maximum distance you can cause damage from?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/159459)" and "[What build maximizes reach?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/111256)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### 35 Feet (40 feet with an optional rule) without shenanigans.

Here's what we need:

- [Bugbear](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/bugbear#BugbearTraits)'s Long-Limbed trait adds 5 feet.
- [Battlemaster Fighter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#BattleMaster)'s Lunging Strike adds 5 feet.
- [Way of the Four Elements Monk](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#WayoftheFourElements)'s Fangs of the Fire Snake adds 10 feet.
- Rolling 51-55 on the [Flesh Warping table](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/bgdia/avernus#FleshWarpingTable) after contacting demon ichor in Avernus adds 5 feet.
- [Potion of Giant Size](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/potion-of-giant-size) adds 5 feet

For a grand total of 35 feet.

Using the optional Mixing Potions rules, roling a 91-99 on the [Potion Miscibility table](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/treasure#MagicItemCategories) while drinking a second potion of some kind can double the increase to reach granted by the Potion of Giant Size:

> The numerical effects and duration of one potion are doubled. If neither potion has anything to double in this way, they work normally.

This brings the total to 40 feet.

#### 1030 feet with shenanigans.

Same build as above, except we take the [Echo Knight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#EchoKnight) subclass instead of Battlemaster. The Echo Knight has two important features. Manifest Echo, which says:

> When you take the Attack action on your turn, any attack you make with that action can originate from your space or the echo’s space. You make this choice for each attack.

And Echo Avatar, which says:

> You can temporarily transfer your consciousness to your echo. As an action, you can see through your echo’s eyes and hear through its ears. During this time, you are deafened and blinded. You can sustain this effect for up to 10 minutes, and you can end it at any time (requires no action). While your echo is being used in this way, it can be up to 1,000 feet away from you without being destroyed.

You use Manifest Echo and Echo Avatar, as well as having the relevant features listed above, and you can make an unarmed strike from the Echo's space, and it can be up to 1030 feet away from where you actually are. The language of Manifest Echo is actually very important here:

> When **you** take the Attack action on your turn, any attack **you** make with that action can originate from your space or the echo’s space. You make this choice for each attack.

The feature is clear that **you** are making the attack that is originating from the Echo's space, and since your reach for the unarmed strike is 30 feet, we can get out to 1030 feet.

Comment: With Unearthed Arcana there is the Primeval Guardian Ranger's Guardian Soul feature adding 5 more to reach. There's also the option of becoming gargantuan or another larger size which doesn't increase you *reach* but it does allow you to attack more total squares

Comment: [This Q&A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/179763/62294) details why I didn't (can't) use Eldritch Claw Tatoo.